# Invalid configuration in configuration file: /home/hadoop/hive.config"

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, hive, emr, amazon-emr

i am trying to schedule hive jobs using Amazon -EMR . I have followed the instructions mentioned in 
the link

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/kinesis-hive-scripted-queries.html

However I am getting the error

```
"Invalid configuration in configuration file: /home/hadoop/hive.config"
    SCRIPT_TYPE=hive
    SCRIPTS=/home/hadoop/crontab/load.q
    LOG_DIR=/tmp/cronlogs
    JAVA_HOME=/etc/alternatives/jre
    HADOOP_HOME=
```

the contents of my hive file is as follows :

```
SCRIPT_TYPE=hive
SCRIPTS="/home/hadoop/crontab/load.q"
LOG_DIR=/tmp/cronlogs
```

Could someone help me understand where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

possible options for  **hive.config** are

```
SCRIPT_TYPE=hive
SCRIPTS=/home/hadoop/crontab/user_agents_count.q
LOG_DIR=/tmp/cronlogs
HADOOP_HOME=/usr/lib/hadoop
HIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/hive
```

You probably might be having an  extra config(like JAVA_HOME ) or missing something on this.

Recheck http://emr-kinesis.s3.amazonaws.com/crontab/hive.config and what executor.sh does to find more about the error.